# operator does not exist: jsonb ~~* unknown error

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

I am trying to run this line of code. It is making a sqlalchemy query that is case insensitive for the data.
`precedent_query = and_(Db_obj.data.ilike(f"{{'collections': [{{'idType': {id_type}, 'externalId': {external_id}}}]}}"))`

The docs in sqlalchemy I looked at didn't help me understand what the `jsonb ~~* unknown` part of the error means, is it that it doesnt know what jsonb is?  I have that imported.  Or is it the ~~* that is unknown?

Any help or better solutions to a case insensitive version of this(`precedent_query = and_(Db_obj.data.contains({'collections': [{'idType': id_type, 'externalId': external_id}]}))`) would be greatly appreciated

My error is

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/web/answers/api/answers/views.py", line 107, in answers
    error_message, error_code, response_payload = paginate_response(filters, data, ObjectGroup)
  File "/web/answers/api/helpers.py", line 108, in paginate_response
    count = data.count()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3578, in count
    return self.from_self(col).scalar()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3322, in scalar
    ret = self.one()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3292, in one
    ret = self.one_or_none()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3261, in one_or_none
    ret = list(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3334, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3359, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 988, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1107, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1253, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1473, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1249, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 552, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) operator does not exist: jsonb ~~* unknown
LINE 4: ..."idType": "Foo"}]}' OR db_obj.db_obj.data ILIKE '{''...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. ```
````

Comment: The unknown refers to the type of the 2nd operand literal: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-oper.html

Comment: So in the error it mentions the possibility of needing a type cast.  I tried casting the objects to JSONB with no avail or is this the wrong direction and I should be casting it as something else?  `precedent_query = and_(Answers.data.ilike(f"{{'collections': [{{'idType': {cast(id_type, JSONB)}, 'externalId': {cast(external_id, JSONB)}}}]}}"))`

Comment: The `~~*` operator is [`ILIKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html). So the problem is `db_obj.db_obj.data ILIKE '{...'` and `data` is `jsonb`.

Comment: So the ILIKE operator does not like the use of jsonb.  Is there a good way around this or will I need to look for a different solution?

Comment: It is already JSONB.  You need to cast it to "text", since that is what `ILIKE` (aka `~~*`) operates on.